# Codes for Arrow Keys

Tags: java

In a java program I've added keylistener and I want to check if anyone has pressed the arrow keys or not.Can anyone please help me since I dont know any ascii codes for arrow keys? If possible please give a sample program also.

Comment: The real question that comes to mind is, is `KeyListener` the best choice for what you are trying to do.  While virtual key codes will be the same, you are generally encouraged to use key bindings over `KeyListener` in Swing.

Comment: duplicate of [How to check if the key pressed was an arrow key in Java KeyListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyEvent.VK_UP`
`KeyEvent.VK_DOWN`
`KeyEvent.VK_LEFT`
`KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT`

These are the conditions that you test `e.getKeyCode()` for.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    switch( key ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            // up 
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            // down 
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            // left
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            // right
            break;
     }
}
```

EDIT: I just see now a duplicate of this question here [How to check if the key pressed was an arrow key in Java KeyListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener)