# KeyAdapter listener, nothing happening

Tags: java, jpanel, keylistener

I am currently writing a small program where I'm supposed to use basic transformations. Right now, I'm working on being able to move the polygon by using the arrow keys. Right now I can move it to the right by pressing the mouse, but I'd rather be able to use the right arrow key. However, I haven't been able to no matter which method I tried.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class PolygonPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    Polygon p;
    public PolygonPanel(){
        p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(10, 10);
        p.addPoint(100,50);
        p.addPoint(50,100);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(new MKeyListener());
    }

    class MKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if(keyCode==e.VK_RIGHT){
                System.out.println("FFFFUUUUU");
            }
        }
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        g.fillPolygon(p);   
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("hei");
        for (int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i++) {
            p.xpoints[i] = p.xpoints[i]+10;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class PolygonFrame extends JFrame{
    public PolygonFrame(){
        setTitle("Polygoner");
        setSize(700, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new PolygonPanel());
    }
}

public class Polygonfun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new PolygonFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Nothing happens when I press the right arrow key. I also tried implementing it like this:

```
class PolygonPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,KeyAdapter
```

And then adding the unimplemented methods, but that didn't work either. I know i've probably overlooked something, but I cant seem to figure it out. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you reading this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `this.setFocusable(true);` for your panel.

Should be:

```
public PolygonPanel(){
    p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(10, 10);
    p.addPoint(100,50);
    p.addPoint(50,100);
    addMouseListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(new MKeyListener());
}
```

Comment: You are my hero. Much appreciated.