# How to return keyCode of Character

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have following task to do.

I have char[] text.
I want to check if character which was pressed in JTextField is equal to text[0] = 'a';
I need it to compare two characters even if these characters are spaces.

I have started like this
       ...

```
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {


       int charcode = e.getKeyCode();   


    }
```

Then I don't know how to get keyCode of character.

Comment: Why don't you get the key char instead of the key code? [KeyEvent#getKeyChar()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar())

Comment: Because getKeyChar does not recognize "space".

Comment: Who told you that? It recognizes the space.

Comment: Are you really working with `char[]`? Why not `string`?

Comment: [`KeyEvent.VK_SPACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_SPACE) and other fields in KeyEvent will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " I want to check if character which was pressed in JTextField"

Don't use a `KeyListener` for a `JTextField`. Instead use a `DocumentListener` (which listen for changes in the underlying document of the text field) or a `DocumentFilter` (which will allow you to filter out "real-time" typed character). Without a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish when a space entered is detected, I couldn't recommend which one will be more suitable. But you can go to [How to Write DocumentListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you,but I think if I use your method anyway I will have to compare input characters with getKeyCode method.Am not I right?

Comment: No. You don't use KeyListener at all. Go to the link and learn to use the document listener. Just get the text from the field and check the last character of the string

Answer (score -2):

U have not googled it well....
this is the keys value list.......
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html
this is an example how to check pressed char in java..
[How to check if the key pressed was an arrow key in Java KeyListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener)

Comment: [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer): ***Provide context for links*** - *A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.* ***Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.***