# How to make key 'H' to print some text

Tags: java, swing

For now i only need a basic message to be printed as i'll program what i'll actually need later but my problem is:

```
@Override
    public void init(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        getStateMachine().setState((byte) 1);
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_H) {
        // Do some other stuff here...
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is what code i have for buttons presses. Enter does a task, but H does not.

```
package instructionpackagev1;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Instructions {

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_H) {
        System.out.println("For now, it's a test");
    }


     }

}
```

So in other words the basis is, how do i get the letter 'H' to print a line when pressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if the user is pressing a key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

**if(e.getKeyChar() == 'H')**

Comment: but how would i implement this in?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [public char getKeyChar()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar)? If not, this may be a solution for you.