# how to use arrow keys to move JLabel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, keylistener

to be brief I have a custom object player that extends JLabel and I want to add a listener to my object that allows me to change the position with the arrow keys. Also does Swing have a schedule update method otherwise when I foresee the issue of the key not continuing to respond as I hold the key.

```
public class Player extends JLabel implements Stats{
    private int hp;
    private int bulletcount;
    public Player(int hitpoints, int clip) throws IOException{
        hp=hitpoints;
        bulletcount=clip;
        ImageIcon ship= new ImageIcon("Images/fighterjet.png");
        this.setIcon(ship);
        movement mk= new movement();
        this.addKeyListener(mk);
    }
```

below is my listener class

```
public class movement implements KeyListener {
    boolean pressed;


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode()  == KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)
            e.getComponent().setBounds(1000, 1000, 60, 10000);
            pressed=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

below is my driver

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main window =new Main();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500,500);

        Player uno= new Player(10,50);

        window.add(uno);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("SPACE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Don't try to shift components around a container. This is definitely a case where custom painting should be used.

Comment: Check the pressed key codes. google "swing key code arrow" leads to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener)

Comment: *"Also does Swing have a schedule update method otherwise when I foresee the issue of the key not continuing to respond as I hold the key"* - If I understand the comment correctly, yes, your listener will be called repeatedly while the key is held down, however, I recommend using something like a Swing `Timer` to set up "main loop" from which you can determine the state of some action key and update the state of the player accordingly, this will allow you to better control the movement, as on most OSs, there is a delay between the first key event and the repeated key events

Answer (score 0):

As already said you should use key bindings to handle keyboard events.

Now your JLabel becomes:

```
public class Player extends JLabel implements Stats{
private int hp;
private int bulletcount;

public Player(int hitpoints, int clip) throws IOException{
    hp=hitpoints;
    bulletcount=clip;
    ImageIcon ship= new ImageIcon("Images/fighterjet.png");
    this.setIcon(ship);
    movement mk= new movement();

getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK), "doSomething");
        getActionMap().put("doSomething", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I looked at the links everyone sent me, so that cleared up some of my confusion yet my object still did not respond with my key press and I took the code that you suggested. in place of "char" i put 'w' in place  for my key I used VK_W. In regards to the action performed method I implemented it like so Player.this.setLocation(100,200);

Comment: LayoutManager doesn't care about changes at runtime, there is required  to call revalidate and repaint inside actionPerformed (once time as last code, after all changes are done to already visible Swing GUI)

Comment: Is your key press getting registered? Is the focus fine?